# JComboBox sharing data with TableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablemodel

I have a table with a column "Category" which is rendered with JComboBox. This table holds items Expense and is called "Expense table". JComboBox is created like this: JComboBox(new  DefaultComboBoxModel()).

```
public class Expense {
  Tag category;
}

class Tag {
  String name;
}
```

I wanted to customize Categories. So I created a table "Categories" for adding, removing possible values to Categories. This table uses TagTableModel and operates on field data, which holds ArrayList value.

```
class TagTableModel 
  extends AbstractTableModel {
    ArrayList<Tag> data;
    ...
}
```

Once a user changes a value in "Categories" table: adds category, removes category, edits column "Name" on some row, I would like values in JComboBox to be updated as well.

What are possible ways to make JComboBox to rely on values from TagTableModel?

Comment: you can to returns value from column(s), from AbstractTableModel based on util.List, but then there could be an duplicates, are you sure that value in column can't contains duplicates, in all cases you have to calculating with ....

Comment: implement a TableModelListener that updates the combo's model

Comment: TableModelListener worked just fine! Thank you. How to make this question answered?:)

Comment: How to make this question answered?:) waiting if (@kleopatra) to convert her comment to answer or post own answer (but then can be accepted per 2days, don't know realy, more infos, read FAQ)

Comment: you can answer your own question :-) Flesh out my comment a bit with what you did and post it, for others to find if they search for something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @kleopatra for the idea :)

I used TableModelListener as suggested: created

```
public class CategoryTableModelListener 
    implements TableModelListener
{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
    {
        /** here I get changed row and access object that was in this row and has changed */
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be a better approach to write one model that implements the interfaces for both component types (ComboBoxModel & TableModel). Like this you have only one source of data and don't have to maintain two different models.